# Difference between srcs and non srcs jars?

Tags: java, jar

I have downloaded the selenium.java-2.47.1 java zip and it contains both `selenium-java-2.47.1.jar` and `selenium-java-2.47.1-srcs.jar`.

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-srcs JAR contains just the compiled class files ("binaries", actually byte code), and the srcs jar contains the source code (`.java` files). You only need the non-srcs JAR to compile and run your project, but the source JAR includes the Javadoc. By the way, you could open up the JARs and see this for yourself: a JAR is just a zipped archive.

This is a very common way of releasing Java libraries. Sometimes there is also a Javadoc JAR which contains HTML files.

As you gain experience, you will find that having the source code is useful because (1) documentation is often lacking, and (2) source code can answer questions documentation cannot.